# Writing a REGEX to match the src, height and width attributes of an img tag

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex expression to match the src, width and height attributes on an image tag. The width and height are optional.

I have came up with the following:

```
(?:<img.*)(?<=src=")(?<src>([\w\s://?=&.]*)?)?(?:.*)(?<height>(?<=height=")\d*)?(?:.*)(?<width>(?<=width=")(\d*)?)?
```

expresso shows this matching only the src bit for the following html snippet

```
<img src="myimage.jpg" height="20" />
<img src="anotherImage.gif" width="30"/>
```

I'm hoping I'm really close and someone here can point out what I'm doing wrong, I have a feeling its my optional in between characters bit (?:.*) i've tried making it non greedy to no success. So any pointers?

Comment: Why do you need to use regex? can you not run it through an HTML parsing library and use XMLReader functions instead ?

Comment: Regex syntax is different in different languages.  So which language are you using?  Perl, ruby, something else?

More importantly, consider using a html parser instead of a regex.  Do you think a regex will match if the src is after the width and height, rather than before?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using regular expressions to pull values from HTML is always a mistake. HTML syntax is a lot more complex that it may first appear and it's very easy for a page to catch out even a very complex regular expression.

Use an [HTML Parser](http://www.google.com/search?q=html+parser) instead.

[This question has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677038/how-to-use-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-in-java) and will be asked again.  Regular Expressions do seem like a good choice for this problem, but they're not.

Comment: It was far easier to use a HTML Parser, I used HTMLAgilityPack, so much faster and gives you more control. Many Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Regexes are fundamentally bad at parsing HTML (see [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166) for why).  What you need is an HTML parser.  See [Can you provide an example of parsing HTML with your favorite parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340) for examples using a variety of parsers.

Answer (score 1):

In most regex dialects, `.*` is "greedy" and will overmatch; use `.*?` to match "as little as possible" instead.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have a chance to test it, but maybe this will work for you (note that I didn't use named matches):

```
<img(?:(\s*(src|height|width)\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"\s*)+|[^>]+?)*>
```