# RegExp to get src, width and height attributes from img tags (in PHP)

Tags: php, regex

I have a random, long string of html code (user-entered) - I need to check it for img tags and the respective widths/heights and replace every image instance with a string of proprietary code, so for example

```
Hello world <img src="http://example.com/image.jpg" width="320" height="240" /> this is some random text <img src="http://example.com/cutepuppy.jpg" width="150" height="200" />
```

Needs to be replaced with

```
Hello world [img:http://example.com/image.jpg w:320 h:240] this is some random text [img:http://example.com/cutepuppy.jpg w:150 h:200]
```

Comment: he c̶̮omes he comes the ich​or permeates all

Comment: Oh please just use an HTML parser. The `<center>` cannot hold it is too late

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Your examples isn't valid HTML. Looks more like XHTML to me. If so you should not use an HTML parser, but instead an XML parser (or else make sure you choose an HTML parser that can handle tag soup).

Comment: Like I said, it's user-generated code. It could be html, it could be xhtml, I can't control it. I figured RegExp would be the easiest way to do it.

Comment: fredley - my post has absolutely nothing in common with the one you linked.

Comment: Not to be rude, but you figured incorrectly. Use a parser.

Comment: Well, if I use an html parser with code that is not valid html, that's not going to be any help. Also I have no idea what you mean by "the <center> cannot hold it is too late".

Comment: @anti: it's a Stack Overflow [internet meme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme_(Internet)), see [@bobince's answer to this question: "Regex match open xhtml self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Answer (score 1):

The regex you'll need will be like :

`<img.*src=["'](.*)["'].*width=(\d+).*height=(\d+).*/>`

Then I think you can make the replacement with the correct php function (preg_replace I guess?) and use backreferences like `\1`for the fist matching parenthesis and so on, to retrieve the different values.

But the HTML syntax is too complex to be used with regexp like you will read on every stackoverflow posts on the subject. For example, the example here won't work if you inverse the width and the height.

I think you can find better solutions to your problem just by browsing SO. (Example : [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880062/writing-a-regex-to-match-the-src-height-and-width-attributes-of-an-img-tag))

Comment: Thanks. Yeah as suggested in the comments, I'll try to find a parser that works.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't answer your question, but wouldn't it be easier to:

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("http://example.com/image.jpg");
```

and then you don't need to rely on valid html in the markup.

Comment: It would if the host I was using allowed me to use getimagesize on remote files. Alas, it doesn't. Good answer though!