# Ask the help for regular expressions in Android

Tags: java, html, android

I am a beginner on developing Android's application. I have some problems about using regular expressions in Android.

In my application, I had write some code for get back the source code of a html page which I had turn it in String datatype. 
And now I want to use regular expressions to retrieve some details in the html tags of this page. So, what should I do for it?

for example, in the html code,

```
<HTML>
.......
<TABLE class=tb_info cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>
<TR>
<TD class=pro_name vAlign=center colSpan=5>Abby Poon</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD class=pro_name vAlign=center colSpan=5>Peter Pan</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
.........
</HTML>
```

And now I want to get back the value "Abby Poon" and "Peter Pan" which is in a table called "tb_info" and in a  called "pro_name" for both two values.
Can anyone teach me how I can do it? Or you may give me some reference page for it with Android.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

### [Do not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not) [parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) [using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677038/how-to-use-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-in-java/677045#677045) [regular expressions](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/).

Instead, use an [HTML Parser](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html).

Answer (score 0):

HTML is not a regular language, therefore you cannot use Regular Expressions against it 100% successfully.  You need to use some sort of HTML parser instead.

[You don't want to be driven insane.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)