# regular expressions in java

Tags: java

how can use a regular expression to extract a links in a web page(suppose i get the html page as a text file) using java?

Comment: obligatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 2):

This previously posted question should help you

[How to use regular expressions to parse HTML in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677038/how-to-use-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-in-java)

Essentially you should really look at using a HTML parser

Answer (score 1):

Agree that HTML parser will make your life easier if you can include it with your build - I've used Jericho HTML Parser for something similar in the past...