# Extracting html link using java Regular expression

Tags: java, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use regular expressions to parse HTML in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677038/how-to-use-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-in-java)

now want to extract "/hc/review/show/29439" from

```
   <a href="/hc/review/show/29439" class="green-arrow">Read more</a>
```

how should I write java regular expression for this ???

Answer (score 1):

Pretty exactly answered [on this page](http://www.dscripts.net/2010/09/04/extract-hyperlinks-from-html-using-regular-expression-in-java/).