# Regular expression for span

Tags: java, html, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use regular expressions to parse HTML in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677038/how-to-use-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-in-java)

From the following code, I want to extract HREF based on span item. Suppose I give input as "Home", then I should be able to get the href before it. What is the regular expression for the same in Java

This is the HTML code

```
<a class="first navibar_link" href="/mnetbank/servlet/Main?prefix=0003015106-680870747659702266"><span>Home</span></a>
```

Comment: I don't know, but I only see "Home" as "This is the HTML code" ... I guess it was just an accident.

Comment: I this post incomplete?  Where is the HTML?

Comment: This is the code he is using <a class="first navibar_link" href="/mnetbank/servlet/Main?prefix=0003015106-680870747659702266"><span>Home</span></a> but is not well formated

Comment: I see. He should'nt use regex. He should try with an xml-Parser.

Comment: Guys thanks for ur replies. Actually I posted only limited content. Not the complete HTML code. If I can get it from this HTML code also would be fine. is there any regular expression for the same?

Comment: This question is asked very very often. I see it nearly every day. Just look at the Related section at the right of the page. The answer is invariably : don't use regexes to parse HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use regular expressions for extracting data from HTML, it's too complicated to get it right. Use [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html) instead.