# Reading Website Contents Java

Tags: java, android, html

I'm developing an android application where in a website I programmatically submit data into search box and retrieve results by Java.

I get the data by using `URLConnect` Java. I get the source code ie html code......

```
Urlconnection a = .connect to host

getinputstream

read data
```

I use these functions
now if the site has content like:

```
sahil
3/5 patel chowk
965955
```

since these details will be inside html tags i want to extract this information  . any idea?

Comment: solved problem . thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look at JSoup: http://jsoup.org/ its an HTML parser should do what you need.

Comment: amazing .. even i heard about JSON. wats dat

Comment: JSoup is a Java library for working with real-world HTML. It provides a very convenient API for extracting and manipulating data, using the best of DOM, CSS, and jquery-like methods.

Answer (score 0):

in my guess using regular expression in this case will be a good fit to you: [How to use regular expressions to parse HTML in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677038/how-to-use-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-in-java)

Comment: but since page is very big. i need to extract a very small area..how to jump their dirct

Comment: with using libraries like @David already mentioned its easy to have a large page as input. its parsing the whole page for a specific condition you gave the parser as input. so dont worry about that. Just have a look to JSoup and the samples provided on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JTiddy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) It is easy to use java library for extracting content from html page.