# I need to count all urls on page

Tags: java, jsp, applet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use regular expressions to parse HTML in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677038/how-to-use-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-in-java)

I need to count all url on page with Java. I'm beginer in Java. I need advice in what technology I should use to count url. I think i can use regular expressions to detect url and count urls, but I'm not shure

Comment: I would first write a program that can download the page. Have you gotten that far? If you are having a problem with something particular post some code showing what you have tried.

Comment: We need more. Please confirm: you want a JAVA algorithm that open a connection to an URL, get the HTML content, and count the number of `<a></a>` tags within it?

Comment: @sp00m & km1: user1595557 already states `I'm beginer in Java`. `I need advice in what technology ..`, so I don't think so he/she will clearly understands what you both are getting at (though the questions you have asked see logical), and I think user1595557 requires some hint or starting point to try out something. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the stupid questions. Full task is :

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a count of url passed to applet? jQuery would easily give you that as in:
 `var aCnt = $('a').size();` `aCnt` being the count of `a` tags. More on it [here](http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/DOMM-4U8FM6/).

Comment: The OP didn't speak about JavaScript, let alone jQuery...

Comment: true, but mentioned applet, also mentions " I need advice in what technology I should use to count url."

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.your-url.com/").get();
Elements links = doc.select("a");
int count = links.size();
```