# Regex to remove HTML tags including H1, H2

Tags: java, html, regex, tags

Right now I'm using `String.replaceAll("\\<(.*?)\\>", "");`
But it doesn't remove the '1' in `<h1></h1>` tags. Is there any way to do this without using a seperate method for every possible tag?

Comment: [as the answer suggest, don´t use regex on html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677038/how-to-use-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-in-java)

Comment: Can't reproduce by the way, that regex will strip a String containing `<h1></h1>` without leaving a `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");
```