# html attributes cleaning with java

Tags: java, html, regex

I have a task from school to remove everything from html tags except on a few attributes like class, id, alt, src, name and href.

For example, we have a HTML file:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<h1 value="something" class=header>Header</h1>
<div id="article1" class="article" name="something" >
<img clsas="mistake" src="picture.jpg" id="pict1" class="image_article" alt="picture" />
<p class="article_text" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing. </p>
<a href="article.html" title="More">Více</a>
</div>
```

And the result should be like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<h1 class=header>Header</h1>
<div id="article1" class="article" >
<img src="picture.jpg" id="pict1" class="image_article" alt="picture" />
<p class="article_text" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing. </p>
<a href="article.html">Více</a>
</div>
```

I tried something like this:

```
String opr = html.replaceAll("<([a-zA-Z]+)[^<>]*(class|id)(=\".+?\")[^<]*(class|id)(=\".+?\")[^<]*>", "<$1 $2$3 $4$5 >");
```

But it only works on HTML tags that are both of attributes class and id. Can someone help please?

Comment: they told you to do so with `regex`? If so, tell them that this idea is plain stupid because that´s not what `regex` is supposed to do. Use a proper html parser and work with it in order to manipulate the html.

Comment: Yes i have to do this with regex.

Comment: Even if it´s just an example, show them [the accepted answer to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677038/how-to-use-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-in-java), regex is not the tool to manipulate `html` with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid regular expressions for such need, as it will be very complex if you want to have it right, so it would be hard to maintain. You should use an `HTML parser` instead like [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org) then clean up each element by removing all the unwanted attributes as next:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<html>\n" +
    " <head></head>\n" +
    " <body>\n" +
    "<table><div class=\"wrapper\">\n" +
    "<h1 value=\"something\" class=header>Header</h1>\n" +
    "<div id=\"article1\" class=\"article\" name=\"something\" >\n" +
    "<img clsas=\"mistake\" src=\"picture.jpg\" id=\"pict1\" class=\"image_article\" alt=\"picture\" />\n" +
    "<p class=\"article_text\" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing. </p>\n" +
    "<a href=\"article.html\" title=\"More\">Více</a>\n" +
    "</div></body></html>"
);
for (Element element : doc.getAllElements()) {
    for (Attribute attribute : element.attributes()) {
        switch (attribute.getKey()) {
            case "class":
            case "id":
            case "alt":
            case "src":
            case "name":
            case "href":
                break;
            default:
                element.removeAttr(attribute.getKey());
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(doc);
```

**Output:**

```
<html>
 <head></head> 
 <body> 
  <div class="wrapper"> 
   <h1 class="header">Header</h1> 
   <div id="article1" class="article" name="something"> 
    <img src="picture.jpg" id="pict1" class="image_article" alt="picture"> 
    <p class="article_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing. </p> 
    <a href="article.html">Více</a> 
   </div>
  </div>
  <table></table>
 </body>
</html>
```