# Error while trying to find text between HTML tags

Tags: java, android, html

I am trying to dynamically extract text that is between some HTML tags like `<h4>,<h3>,<h2>` on an Android app. I have tried to write a code but the app crashes as soon as I try to call the function.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Extractor {

    String code = ""; //--------------------------------Some HTML Code
    List<Integer> fromIndex , toIndex;
    List<String> headings;


    public void populate() {

        int index;

        ArrayList<String> oTag = new ArrayList<>();
        oTag.add("<h4>");
        oTag.add("<h3>");
        oTag.add("<h2>");

        for (String ot : oTag) {
            index = code.indexOf(ot);
            while (index >= 0) {
                fromIndex.add(index + ot.length());
                index = code.indexOf(ot, index + ot.length());
            }
        }

        ArrayList<String> cTag = new ArrayList<>();
        cTag.add("</h4>");
        cTag.add("</h3>");
        cTag.add("</h2>");

        for (String ct : cTag) {
            index = code.indexOf(ct);
            while (index >= 0) {
                toIndex.add(index);
                index = code.indexOf(ct, index + ct.length());
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0 ; i < toIndex.size() ; i++)
        {
            headings.add(code.substring(fromIndex.get(i),toIndex.get(i)));
        }
    }
}
```

The error shown by Android Studio is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                      at com.myuser.hplap.myapp.Extractor.populate(Extractor.java:50)
                      at com.myuser.hplap.myapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:38)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21158)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
```

The variable `code` is sent from an activity with full HTML code of the webpage but to represent it simply, I have included it into the same class.

Also, while searching for a solution for this, I have seen many other approaches to the same problem (eg: regex, XPath, HtmlCleaner, etc.) but I am confused as to which would suit me the best. Could someone recommend a tried and tested method for doing the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never initialize the `List<String> headings`.

And about the HTML tags issue, I think these would get you started:

- [HTML Parsing Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677038/how-to-use-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-in-java).
- [HTML Parsing Via Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

If you already read these, and did not get the answer you wanted (for example: [what's wrong with HTMLParser?](http://search.clearch.org/?direct_search=2&reason=2&uid=399271&q=java%20html%20parser)) - then please elaborate about your prerequisites.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, after initializing 
`List<Integer> fromIndex = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 List<Integer> toIndex = new ArrayList<Integer>();`
 and 
`headings = new ArrayList<String>();`
the app works perfectly.

I will read into your suggested links, do you think that implementing those would be better than using what I already have?

Comment: Depends. If this is production code - fully tested and documented External API is always better IMO. If this is homework/study/messing-around - trying thongs for your self is totally better for understanding and custom features. Think about your needs - and make a decision. :)

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.