# Unable to know how to use the substitution

Tags: java, regex

I've a string like below

```
<a name="1.F"></a>
```

I'm trying to extract only the value *name* value. And the regex I'm using to get this done is.

Search string

`<a name=\"(\d)+(\.)(\w)+\"?>`

Replace String

```
$1$2$3
```

**Result:**  Here the Result that I get is what is in between **

search result :

```
**<a name="1.F">**</a>
```

Current Replace Result:

```
1.F</a>
```

Expected Replace Result:

```
1.F
```

please let me know, how can we get the Expected result.

Thanks

Comment: Use `[^"]` instead of `\w`? Also, you might want the quantifiers inside the groups.

Comment: Your `(\w)+` is matching till the end. Use `[^"]`

Comment: Is the string always in this format? Do you really need to pre-validate it with `\d+\.\w+`? Note that all you need to extract a string between double quotes is a couple of string methods. Splitting with `"` and getting the second item could also be an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your example, why don't you go for a simple solution? Like: your value is enclosed by double quotes - so just use that knowledge and capture everything between those two "quotes".

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class RegexTest {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s = "<a name=\"1.F\"></a>";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<a name=\\\"(.*)\\\"");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
      System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
  }
}
```

prints:

1.F

You see, you wouldn't even need a regex for that, you could use [String.indexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) in order to quickly fetch the position of that quotation mark.

If on the other hand, your example was just simplified, and your real input is much complicated (like in: real HTML or XML) ... then simply forget about using regexes in the first place (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677038/how-to-use-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-in-java) for why that is).

Comment: Hi @GhostCat, this doesn't seem working since the `.*` will be captirung till  `</a>`, moreover I've posted this after verifying this. :)

Comment: @GhostCat, your regex would capture everything between `"` so it was correct. The result was in the first capture group.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED

@user3872094 I have just test my code by yours pattern `<a name=\"(\d)+(\.)(\w)+\"?>` and it gives output `1.F`. So I suspect the bug comes from your Java code

```
    String s = "**<a name=\"1.F\">**</a>";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<a name=\"(\\d)+(\\.)(\\w)+\"?>");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1) + m.group(2) + m.group(3));
    }
```

=>> 1.F

Comment: Hi @AntonyDao, can you please explain me whats going behind the scenes. Thansks

Comment: Hi @user3872094 after testing your pattern, I think yours is correct. Please see my updated answer.