# Removing all <br> from the end of a String

Tags: java, android

Suppose I have a `String` with multiple `<br>` tags **at the end** of the String,

how can I remove all at once?

I've tried using `if(text.endsWith("<br>") text.replace("<br>", "");` but that only removes one of all the others..

Comment: `text.replaceAll("<br>", "");`

Comment: `replace` replaces all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use regular expressions to parse HTML in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677038/how-to-use-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-in-java)

Comment: @PavelSmirnovthat will remove all the `<br>` tags in the string, I only want to remove the multiple tags in the end of the String

Comment: text.replace('<br>', ''); You can see doc..https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: @Jabongg read the que. again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to remove them at the end of the string:

```
text = text.replaceAll("(<br>)*$", "");
```

The `$` anchor is necessary to ensure that this doesn't replace other occurrences earlier in the string.

You can do it without regex, if you want:

```
int a = text.length();
while (a >= "<br>".length() && text.regionMatches(a - "<br>".length(), "<br>", 0, "<br>".length())) {
  a -= "<br>".length();
}
text = text.substring(0, a);
```

Comment: regex is better and simple.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

`text = text.replaceAll("<br>","").replaceAll("<br>","");`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a specific method in java to do this. However, you can use a while loop to achieve this :

```
String text = "hello world <br><br><br>";
while (text.endsWith("<br>")) {
    text = text.substring(0, text.length() - 4);
}
```

Comment: `replace` replaces all

Answer (score 0):

In these cases, you should take a look at the official Javadoc documentacion:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

The method you're looking for is public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement), which replaces all the occurrences of the specified pattern.
In your case it should be something like this:

```
fullText.replaceAll("<br>", ""),
```

where fullText is the variable that contains all the text you want to process.

**EDIT**: From your comments I gather you only want to delete the br at the end of the string and I assume that **text** is compromised of multiple lines.
Since replaceAll can use regular expression, you should be able to do something like this:

```
fullText.replaceAll("<br>\\n", "\\n"),
```

**EDIT 2**: I wish I could comment...Disregard my answer, please, I think the correct answer is **Andy Turner**'s one. It does seem to work fine at only deleting the **br** at the end of the line.

Comment: `replace` replaces all

Comment: You're right, if you're not using a regular expression to process the string then you can use replace instead of replaceAll. In this case I've updates the answer since it needs a regEx.

Comment: @George newlines don't only occur at the end of strings, nor do they necessarily appear at the end of a string. And in particular, there is no newline at the end of OP's string.

Comment: You're right, the problem was that I didn't fully understand the question, but I already edited the answer to reflect that I was wrong. Thanks for the input.